# Sorting characters in a file in C

Tags: c, string, file, frequency

How can I sort the characters in a file without using another file? I've been thinking about saving them in a string but what if there are lots of chars? Also, I've been thinking about creating a frequency array (based on ASCII code) but again, the file could be hundreds of MB.

Thank you!

Comment: It simply count each character. `size_t counter[256]={0};..counter[c]++;`

Comment: Do you actually want to sort the *characters*? So the file `Hello world` sorted would be `deHllloorw`?

Comment: Do you really mean characters? If so, there can only be 255 (assuming ascii) so keep a frequency count - if you use an int for each bucket, that's still only 1k. Themn write them out in order, repeating each character the number of times it occurs in the file

Comment: Yes, I mean characters: `Hello World` would be `Hdellloorw`

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that by "character" you mean what C calls a "character" (`char`); multibyte and wide character sets are out of scope. In that case, there are only `UCHAR_MAX + 1` (often 256) distinct characters, which is a small enough set for a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). Essentially what you need to do is read the whole file, count the occurrences of each character, and print each character as many times as it appears. Use an array of `unsigned long int` because that's bigger than any offset than `ftell()` can return, and make it `UCHAR_MAX + 1` elements long because that's how many distinct characters are possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // for EXIT_FAILURE
#include <limits.h>  // for *_MAX

// "unsigned long int" chosen to match the ftell() limit,
// and numeric variables at top level start out zeroed
unsigned long int occurrences[UCHAR_MAX + 1];

// static assertion to make sure we're on a "sane" platform
// with INT_MAX larger than UCHAR_MAX
extern char staticassert1[INT_MAX > UCHAR_MAX ? 1 : -1];

int main(const int argc, const char *const *argv) {
  FILE *infp = NULL;
  int ch;

  if (argc < 2) {  // ensure a filename was provided
    fputs("error: no filename\n", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  infp = fopen(argv[1], "rt");
  if (!infp) {  // ensure the file can be read
    perror(argv[1]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // count each character; EOF is a value distinct from
  // all characters
  for(ch = fgetc(infp); ch != EOF; ch = fgetc(infp)) {
    // cast to unsigned because arrays have no negative index
    occurrences[(unsigned char)ch] += 1;
  }

  // once ch becomes EOF, the file has been read
  // to either its end or an error
  if (ferror(infp)) {
    fclose(infp);
    perror(argv[1]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // close the successfully read file
  fclose(infp);
  infp = NULL;  // it's good practice to cut off dangling pointers early

  // now print all characters in the file in sorted order
  for (ch = 0; ch <= UCHAR_MAX; ++ch) {
    for (; occurrences[ch] > 0; --occurrences[ch]) {
      fputc(ch, stdout);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detalied answer. On your last lines doesn't stdout print the chars on screen?

Comment: @Stefan The `stdout` stream writes the characters to whatever your operating system defines as standard output. On workstation-like systems with a screen, such as Windows and GNU/Linux, `stdout` is usually a terminal emulator, but it can be redirected to a file or one side of a pipe. Feel free to clarify your Q to say where you want the sorted result written. Did you mean write them to the same file?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. Yes, I mean save them in the same file.

Comment: @Stefan You could change this program to open an output file (using `fopen()`) and write the characters to that file instead of to `stdout`. But writing to the same filename that you just read is unsafe because if the computer loses power in the middle, the original file cannot be recovered.

Comment: Regarding the writing to the same file: I changed the file acces to `"r+w"`, and tried printing the characters with `fprintf(infp,ch);`, however the initial file remains intact. I understand the risks of writing in the same file, however this is what my problem asks. Regarding this, a small thought I had: Is it possible to sort the the file using a sorting algorithm, like merge sort and keeping each char in a buffer? `char * buffer = (char*)malloc(2*sizeof(char))` ?

Comment: @Stefan DO NOT USE `printf` family functions without a well-formed format string! It's a bad habit to get into that can cause and has caused security vulnerabilities. Look up `rewind()` and `fputc()` in a C standard library reference.